# Use a custom domain and point to Tumblr blog

Tags: domains, redirects, dns, no-www, tumblr

My domain `mydomain.com` is registered with GoDaddy. I wish to host my Tumblr blog on this domain with Nearly Free Speech hosting.

My active nameservers at GoDaddy already point to my authoritative ones at Nearly Free Speech which is working. However I'm baffled as to how to get my correct configuration to point to my Tumblr.

Preferably I'd like

(A) my domain `http://mydomain.com` to host the blog and have `http://www.mydomain.com` redirect also to `http://mydomain.com`.

If this is too difficult my next preference is

(B) to have `http://www.mydomain.com` host the blog whilst `http://mydomain.com` redirects to `http://www.mydomain.com`

My third preference is to have

(C) a sub-domain like `http://tumblr.mydomain.com` or `http://tumblr.mydomain.com` to host the blog and I guess have `http://mydomain.com` and `http://www.mydomain.com` both redirect to it.

I've tried having two aliases `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` pointing to my permanent Nearly Free Speech IP at `mydomain.nfshost.com` and when I try to add:

(1) an A record pointing `mydomain.com` to the IP ***66.6.44.4*** as per Tumblr's ***[instructions](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains)*** it tells me I already have the bare domain as an alias so I cant do that.

(2) the A record on the `www.mydomain.com` alias.
I can do this with either `www.mydomain.com` set as an alias or not.
But when I tried this with `mydomain.com` set as the canonical name the result when visiting either `mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com` was both of them continually redirecting to each other until an error was thrown.

So I was wondering if there is a ninja that could save me some hair-pulling and tell me the correct way to config A, or else B, or else C.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on how to use a custom domain name with Tumblr
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

To redirect from domain.com to www.domain.com place the code below in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tumblr tells me to add an A-record to point to domain.com
the only way i can do that in NFS DNS settings is to first add an alias to www.domain.com which is a cname-record and then add an Arecord pointing domain.com to 66.6.44.4 
It wont let me add an Arecord when there arent aliases setup and it wont if domain.com is already an alias.
So atm i have a cname record from www.domain.com to domain.nfshost.com and an a-record from domain.com to 66.6.44.4 
and i also have domain.com set in Tumblr's settings.
The problem (i think) is that www.domain.com will still not be pointing to tumblr.

Comment: im unsure about your answer Anagio, because i want option A preferably that is www.domain.com redirecting to domain.com and that domain.com being the tumblr